# Update azure tag using AZ CLI

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

trying to update all the tags in a resource in one shot using Azure CLI any ideas

This is code I tried

```
  jsonrtag=$(az resource show -g examplegroup -n examplevnet --resource-type "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks" --query tags)
    rt=$(echo $jsonrtag | tr -d '"{},' | sed 's/: /=/g')
    az resource tag --tags $rt Project=Redesign -g examplegroup -n examplevnet --resource-type "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
```

Comment: please format your code and tell us about the errors you got.

Comment: The above snippet seems to work alright. What more are you looking to accomplish that this doesn't solve?

Comment: i am looking into update all the tags under single resource in single shot

Comment: Do the commands you used meets your requirements?

Comment: No i am trying it via Power shell script instead of azure cli

Comment: Why does it cannot meet your requirements? You can add more details about your expecting result.

Answer (score 0):

An example to add tags to a resource without existing tags, use:

```
$r = Get-AzResource -ResourceName examplevnet -ResourceGroupName examplegroup
Set-AzResource -Tag @{ Dept="IT"; Environment="Test" } -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
```

An example to add tags to a resource that has existing tags, use:

```
$r = Get-AzResource -ResourceName examplevnet -ResourceGroupName examplegroup
$r.Tags.Add("Status", "Approved")
Set-AzResource -Tag $r.Tags -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
```

For more information, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags#powershell) document.

Hope this helps! Cheers!